# How can I limit Facebook oauth to only Instagram Business accounts?

Tags: facebook, authentication, graph, oauth, instagram

Within our application we would like to provide [automation features for Instagram Business users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview).  The [Instagram API is migrating to Facebook graph](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/), so we have implemented authentication through that.  The problem is that we don't want ALL Facebook users to be able to authenticate, only Instagram Business accounts.

Is there a way we can configure the OAuth setup so that it only lets in the user type that we want?

Otherwise it seems we would be left to do this within application code after the authentication process is complete, which would be a pretty poor user experience (eject the user after they've authenticated).

We're currently [using Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login) to perform the OAuth integration, but would be open to implementing manually if it provides a better user experience.

Comment: No, I don't think that is possible. You will have to check yourself, after they logged in. Depending on the context you present your app login in, I'd recommend you make it clear to user there that this makes little sense if they don't have any IBA connected to their user account to begin with, before they click a login button.

Comment: Plus, look on the bright side (seasonal reference ;-), it gives you a chance to catch the numbnuts who might log in using one of their several accounts (not allowed doesn't mean people don't have them), one which does not have an IBA connection. A blunt FB error message "This app is not available to you" might basically come across as a "get lost", whereas when you catch that inside your app, you could go more like, "sure you logged in with the right account there, maybe try again ...?"

Comment: Interesting... thanks for the feedback @CBroe.